# Javascript: How to populate text field with async value before submitting form?

Tags: javascript, async-await, form-submit

I want to submit a transaction from the client to Ethereum blockchain, get back a transaction hash, and then submit this hash to my backend.

On the front-end I have a form like this:

```
<form id="formConfirm" method="POST" action="/step2" onSubmit="processStep1">
  <input id="textWalletAddress" name="walletAddress" type="text" readonly />
  <input id="textEncodedFunctionCall" th:value="${encodedFunctionCall}" readonly />
  <input type="text" id="textTxHash" readonly />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Inside the function, I want to submit the transaction, get back the corresponding hash, and populate a field with it so that I can push it to my backend.

```
async function processStep1(e) {
  // edit1: trying out preventDefault
  alert('Before preventDefault');
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('After preventDefault');

  let efc = document.getElementById('textEncodedFunctionCall').value;
  let walletAddress = document.getElementById('textWalletAddress').value;
  const txParams = {
    to: CONTRACT,
    from: walletAddress,
    'data': efc
  };
  
  if (window.ethereum) {
    try {
      const txHash = await window.ethereum.request({
        method: "eth_sendTransaction",
        params: [txParams]
      });
      document.getElementById('textTxHash').value = txHash;
      // how/where do I preventDefault()?
    } catch (err) {
      alert('ERROR! ' + err);
    }
  } else {
    alert('MetaMask is not installed!');
  }
}
```

The problem I encounter is that the form goes ahead with the submission without the hash. The transaction does go through (with MetaMask prompts and all) but on my backend I get an error.

I read that I am supposed to `preventDefault()` but I am not sure how to apply it. Can someone guide me on how to do this? Plain JavaScript would be the most ideal as I am trying to reduce dependencies on external libraries.

---

Edit1: I tried `preventDefault` at the beginning but I don't even see any alerts.

Edit2: Added the fields that were missing in my question

Comment: `onSubmit="processStep1()"` remove the `()` here

Comment: `async function processStep1() {` then change this to `async function processStep1(e) {`

Comment: then `add e.preventDefault()` inside the function

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw is there a specific place I should add `preventDefault()`? Start/end of function?

Comment: I usually like to put it in the beginning of the function

Comment: Are the `textEncodedFunctionCall` and `textWalletAddress` fields in the same form?

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw edited my question with the changes you proposed, still doesn't work

Comment: @EmielZuurbier yes they are, I edited my question to add in those two fields.

Comment: I see that all your fields are `readonly`. If that were the case then it would make more sense to fill the `textTxHash` field before the user *can* even submit.

Comment: @user10931326 can check my answer?

Comment: Also if the user could not be interested in the hash you can use `<input type="hidden" />` to not show it, or just hold it in a js variable

Comment: @EmielZuurbier the problem is I need to get the user to confirm the form submission, after which I submit the transaction to Ethereum blockchain to obtain the corresponding hash - all while still on the client side. After I get back the hash, I want to push it to my backend for further processing. I hope this makes sense :)

Comment: @DDomen yes the hash will be hidden eventually; I keep it visible for development/debugging purposes only

Comment: I would consider to rethink the process, if the server needs the hash and not the client would be more secure to make a call to ethereum from the server with the client submitted data, instead of calling from the client. Then you can also transmit back the hash from server to the client. A malicious person could send to your server a fake eth hash

Comment: @DDomen that was my initial plan, but I couldn't get it to work on the server-side. Also because most tutorials I found online do these on the client-side...

Comment: Ok not the best.... So you need XHR after the `event.preventDefault`, check the answer

Comment: @user10931326 I understand. The point I'm trying to make is that you immediately get the hash with the values from the form (as the form is prefilled), fill in the hash input, and *then* allow your user to submit (for example by enabling and disabling the form). IMO that would be a lot more user friendly as the user can take amply time to actually see the hash and sees that their credentials are working. And it will save you the hassle of having to manually submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'd go with:

1. Removing `onSubmit="processStep1()"` and replacing it with javascript: `document.getElementById('formConfirm').onsubmit = processStep1;`. Note the lack of `()` here! EDIT: as someone already pointed out, removing () in `onSubmit="processStep1()"` should also do the trick
2. Then, your function gets an event as parameter, co you can do `async function processStep1(event) { ... }`
3. Now the last thing is to call `event.preventDefault()` somewhere at the beginning. Remember that you are preventing default action, so you are not submitting the form - you probably want to use [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to submit the form manually.

Other than that you can replace `input type="submit"` with a custom button with your function on click, so you don't have to call `event.preventDefault()`. But imo no big difference.

Comment: The solution is not working because when you prevent the default behaviour of a `submit` event it whill not trigger the form's call to the action anymore, so you need to contact the backend "by hand"

Comment: Wrote that in 3. :P

Answer (score 0):

Some errors:

1. `onSubmit` takes a function and not a function call so it should be:

```
<form ... onSubmit="processStep1"> ...
```

2. If you want to stop the form action you need to call the `preventDefault` method of the event, which stops the browser to contacting the form action at first place:

```
async function processStep1(event) {
   // I suggest as first row so you are sure
   // the form will stop before any other operation/error
   // made by this function
   event.preventDefault();
   ...
```

3. You then need to call your backend with a [`XHR` (XMLHttpRequest - MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?retiredLocale=it) because you stopped the normal call that your browser would have done (by preventing the default of the event):

```
function sendForm(form) {
   var formData = new FormData();
   var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');

   inputs.forEach(function(input) {
      var data;
      // simplified version for files (since it seems you don't need it)
      if (input.type === 'file') { data = input.files[0]; }
      else { data = input.value; }
      formData.append(input.name, data);
   });

   return new Promise(function(y, n) {
      var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
             if (status === 0 || (status >= 200 && status < 400)) { 
                y(xhr.responseText);
          }
          else { n(xhr); }
      };
      xhr.open(form.method, form.action);
      xhr.send(formData);
   });
}

async function processStep1(event) {
   ...
   // at the end of your function
   try {
     var response = await sendForm(this);
     // threat response
   } catch(ex) {
     /// threat exceptions
   }
}
```

For more info on [`FormData Object` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) I suggest you to follow the link for a better reading.

Comment: Would your answer be any different if I have to house the JavaScript code externally in its own js file?

Comment: No would be the same, it would have some problem if you serve the HTML/JS file from the `file://` protocol (for security reasons), for the rest no problem

Answer (score -1):

Here. I just put the whole code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="formConfirm">
      <input id="textWalletAddress" name="walletAddress" type="text" />
      <input id="textEncodedFunctionCall" th:value="${encodedFunctionCall}" />
      <input type="text" id="textTxHash" readonly />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <script>
      const form = document.getElementById("formConfirm")

      async function processStep1(e) {
        // let efc = document.getElementById("textEncodedFunctionCall").value
        // let walletAddress = document.getElementById("textWalletAddress").value
        // const txParams = {
        //   to: CONTRACT,
        //   from: walletAddress,
        //   data: efc,
        // }

        // if (window.ethereum) {
        //   try {
        //     const txHash = await window.ethereum.request({
        //       method: "eth_sendTransaction",
        //       params: [txParams],
        //     })

        //     document.getElementById("textTxHash").value = txHash
        //     // how/where do I preventDefault()?
        //   } catch (err) {
        //     alert("ERROR! " + err)
        //   }
        // } else {
        //   alert("MetaMask is not installed!")
        // }
        document.getElementById("textTxHash").value = "HASH"
      }

      form.addEventListener("submit", async function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        await processStep1()
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: DDomen, I just copied those from the question. what do you mean I've made the tags readonly?

Comment: Run your snippet and see if you can edit any of your inputs

Comment: @DDomen, that's what the questionee has posted in the question right ?

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question. It's merely a tutorial on how to use `preventDefault()`. It's in there twice, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes but still not a solution but just a suggestion